# PHP Session/Cookies Not Working - Multiple Servers

Tags: php, nginx, cluster-computing, moodle

I have an Nginx load balancer load balancing two nginx servers serving PHP content (Moodle) up. They share the same database and use the same sessions directory using an NFS share on a separate server.

I am running PHP 5.4.1 and the latest version of Moodle.

Right now the load balancing works just fine, and I am able to access both worker nodes using the proxy. However, when logging in to Moodle, I get an error saying that cookies are disabled. They obviously are not, and logging into one of the worker nodes works just fine. When accessing the nodes individually, the MoodleSession cookie gets set, but when accessing it through the load balancer, no cookie is set.

I have tried changing the cookie mode to use the MySQL database, but this does not work, either.

What can I do get multiple worker nodes to set cookies that the server is storing in a common directory (NFS)?

Comment: Is there code involved? Otherwise, this seems more appropriate for ServerFault.

Comment: Well, it seems that the PHP `$_SESSION` variables are not setting properly when going through the load balancer.

Comment: That's what I was going for... How is the session initialized? Is it, maybe, IP-based (that obviously wouldn't work with load balancers)? Or anything like that. The question, as it is now, is pure guess work...

Answer (score 1):

Try checking for spaces or unknown characters in config.php. This may be preventing cookies from being set and return that warning.